# Como puedo deshabilitar Shield de Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Donde puedo deshabilitar Shield de Codeigniter 4

Comment: Esa biblioteca se instala por separado, no la contiene el framework

Comment: Es verdad, pero una vez instalada necesito deshabilitarla

Comment: Es ese caso la puedes desinstalar quitandola de `composer.json`, teniendo en cuenta que el código que hayas usado de la biblioteca debes quitarlo ya que no funcionará